# How to use regex in grep shell command

Tags: regex, shell, grep

I am not able to use [-]+[\n][-]+ this regex in shell. Can somebody help to use it with escape characters in grep. I want to find lines like '----\n----' from the file

Comment: Does `\n` stand for a `newline` here or is there really a literal `\n` in the file? In other words, are you looking for a pattern within a single line or over two consecutive lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plain old `grep` uses [Basic Regular Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_basic_and_extended) so you don't have immediate access to the `+` quantifier.  In modern (POSIX) `grep` you *can* use this functionality, but it requires a backslash before the quantifier, like `\+`:

```
grep '-\+\\n-\+' file
```

(notice also the single quotes to prevent the shell from doing its own backslash substitution; and pay attention to how `n` matches just itself and a literal backslash is matched either with a double `\\` to escape it or in a character class `[\]`); or you can use `grep -E` (aka `egrep`) which supports [Extended Regular Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_extended):

```
grep -E '-+\\n-+' file
```

For the record, `[\n]` matches a single character which can be either a literal backslash or a literal `n`.  This construct is called a character class; inexplicably, newcomers seem to want to try to use square brackets for pretty much anything just because they "look like regex", apparently.

Comment: Semi-obviously, if you mean to search for dashes followed by newline followed by more dashes, the approach will be quite different.  `grep` -- and many other command-line regex tools -- does not support matching across line boundaries.